# Pie Chart on Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to draw a pie charts on several locations in a Google Map. Is there a way to draw a google pie chart in a particular location in a Google Map to represent a data set (like population in a particular location/town)?

---

I came up with a solution and below displays the code that I wrote to display a pie chart icon in a particular location.
     I have some other requirement to add event listener to the pi chart icon to display a window with more detailed pie chart. I came up with the code below as a solution for this requirements, but it does not display the window when the icon is clicked. Can you please help to find the issue here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://code.google.com//apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.10&sensor=false&.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load( 'visualization', '1', { packages:['corechart'] });

        function drawChart(marker, data) {


            var options = {'title':'Perception Analysis '+
                    marker.getPosition().toString(),
                'width':400,
                'height':150};

            var node        = document.createElement('div'),
                    infoWindow  = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
                    chart       = new google.visualization.PieChart(node);

            chart.draw(data, options);
            infoWindow.setContent(node);
            infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(),marker);
        }

        function ChartMarker( options ) {
            this.setValues( options );

            this.$inner = $('<div>').css({
                position: 'relative',
                left: '-50%', top: '-50%',
                width: options.width,
                height: options.height,
                fontSize: '1px',
                lineHeight: '1px',
                padding: '2px',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                cursor: 'default'
            });

            this.$div = $('<div>')
                    .append( this.$inner )
                    .css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        display: 'none'
                    });
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

        ChartMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
            $( this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget ).append( this.$div );
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
            this.$div.remove();
        };

        ChartMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
            var marker = this;
            var projection = this.getProjection();
            var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel( this.get('position') );

            this.$div.css({
                left: position.x,
                top: position.y,
                display: 'block'
            })

            this.$inner
                    .html( '<img src="' + this.get('image') + '"/>' )
                    .click( function( event ) {
                        var events = marker.get('events');
                        events && events.click( event );
                    });

            this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( this.$inner[0] );
            this.chart.draw( this.get('chartData'), this.get('chartOptions') );
        };

        function initialize() {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 40.708762, -74.006731 );
            var mapOptions = {
                center: latLng,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    mapOptions);

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                [ 'Task', 'Hours per Day' ],
                [ 'Work', 11 ],
                [ 'Eat', 2 ],
                [ 'Commute', 2 ],
                [ 'Watch TV', 2 ],
                [ 'Sleep', 7 ]
            ]);

            var options = {

                fontSize: 8,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                legend: {position: 'none'}
            };

            var marker = new ChartMarker({
                map: map,
                position: latLng,
                width: '250px',
                height: '100px',
                chartData: data,
                chartOptions: options,
                events: {
                    click: function( event ) {
                        drawChart(this,data)
                    }
                }
            });

        };

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're talking about a pie chart drawn with the [Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), you could use a custom HTML overlay like the one in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/FCPJM/2/):

```
google.load( 'visualization', '1', { packages:['corechart'] });

function ChartMarker( options ) {
    this.setValues( options );

    this.$inner = $('<div>').css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: '-50%', top: '-50%',
        width: options.width,
        height: options.height,
        fontSize: '1px',
        lineHeight: '1px',
        border: '1px solid #888',
        padding: '2px',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        cursor: 'default'
    });

    this.$div = $('<div>')
        .append( this.$inner )
        .css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none'
        });
};

ChartMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

ChartMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    $( this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget ).append( this.$div );
};

ChartMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.$div.remove();
};

ChartMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
    var marker = this;
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel( this.get('position') );

    this.$div.css({
        left: position.x,
        top: position.y,
        display: 'block'
    })

    this.$inner
        .html( '<img src="' + this.get('image') + '"/>' )
        .click( function( event ) {
            var events = marker.get('events');
            events && events.click( event );
        });

    this.chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( this.$inner[0] );
    this.chart.draw( this.get('chartData'), this.get('chartOptions') );
};

function initialize() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 40.708762, -74.006731 );

    var map = new google.maps.Map( $('#map_canvas')[0], {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [ 'Task', 'Hours per Day' ],
        [ 'Work', 11 ],
        [ 'Eat', 2 ],
        [ 'Commute', 2 ],
        [ 'Watch TV', 2 ],
        [ 'Sleep', 7 ]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        fontSize: 8
    };

    var marker = new ChartMarker({
        map: map,
        position: latLng,
        width: '250px',
        height: '100px',
        chartData: data,
        chartOptions: options,
        events: {
            click: function( event ) {
                alert( 'Clicked marker' );
            }
        }
    });
};

$( initialize );
```

Comment: This is good and really helpful. Is it possible to make the pie chart image looks like in http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/patrie-galere-deaths-italian-prisons-since-2002-2012/ ?

Comment: You can do something like that, as in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/FCPJM/16/). The pie charts on that site are using pie charts from the Google API along with a number in the center which is overlaid on top of the chart. They are doing this by using a `<div>` with a CSS `background-image` containing the Chart API image URL, and the content of the `<div>` is the number. You can see what they are doing by using the Chrome (or other browser) DOM inspector to examine one of the pie charts.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had to implement pie-charts as markers for many locations on the map.
Having many locations on the map app also required marker clustering...
In my particular case displaying pie-chart as overlay didn't fit, that's why 
I built simple library.
Maybe saying that it is library is too much because it's just one function for now
that generates pie-char svg node.
Github repository with example how to use function along with google-maps below
[Repository](https://github.com/arekgofi/svg-charts)